# Apache NetBeans 12.3 y eclipse 2021-06 (4.20.0) ,problemas con el jar

Tags: java

En el netbeans me genera el jar pero no lo consigo lanzar desde el sistema, en el editor funciona perfectamente.

Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.3
Java: 16.0.2; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 16.0.2+7-67
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 16.0.2+7-67
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; es_ES (nb)

En eclipse me genera el jar con avisos:(Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0))

-La exportacion de Jar a finalizado con avisos
Detalles:
Exportado con avisos de compilación: AppWin/src/pruu.java,
en este caso si funciona el jar en el sistema,
El codigo es el mismo en los dos editores, es simplemente una ventana
vacía, si ahora que es aun menos que un "Hola mundo" tengo estos problemas, como será cuando termine mi proyecto algo bastante mas complejo, con bases de datos, imágenes, etc...
Me da enteramente igual usar un editor o el otro, pero quisiera solucionar uno de los dos problemas.
Que pasa, o que me falta en el netBeans para que ejecte el jar.
En eclipse a que se refiere este aviso,como se soluciona o hay que ignorarlo.

Muchas gracias a todos soy nuevo en el foro y en java soy un aficionado, perdonen si he faltado a alguna de sus reglas

Answer (score 0):

En Eclipse salta esa ventana al exportar el JAR, cuando en el código te marca alguna advertencia, no eliminaste las importaciones que no estas usando, o dejaste alguna variable sin usar, en si todo lo que te marque en amarillo es una advertencia/aviso, pero no un error, por lo que te dejara exportar sin problemas.

---

En el caso de NetBeans no puedo darte una respuesta acertada, puede ser que compilaste el archivo en una versión de Java superior a la que hay instalada en el sistema, con Eclipse Luna, pasaba que solo podías ejecutarlo en el IDE pero al crear el JAR no abría el programa.

Quizás puedas ejecutarlo desde la Terminal y ver que dice.

```
java -jar C:/Users....Programa.jar
```

Mensaje al intentar ejecutar el archivo JAR, que compile con java 10, pero tengo instalado Java 8 en el sistema:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: main/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```